# robotium: play only one test with android studio

Tags: android-studio, robotium

I have the following Robotium test class:

```
public class StartupActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<StartupActivity>
{
    ...
    public void testFeature1() { ... }
    public void testFeature2() { ... }
    public void testFeature3() { ... }
    ...
}
```

I am using Android Studio to play all my tests.

But How can I play only a single test (testFreature2 for example)?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution: in Android Studio, right-click on the test method and select "Run ..."